# Why do I get different results for finding the peak of memory usage?

Tags: linux, memory-management

In Linux, I am using `/usr/bin/time -f %M` tool (gnu-time) to get the peak of the memory used for a single process/program. But every time that I run this command, I get a different result.

1. What's the reason of this difference?
2. How can I get the accurate value for the maximum memory consumed by a process?

p.s. I've already used other methods like the ones taking snapshots from the memory (like reading from `/proc/pid`), but as my program ends so fast, I don't want anything with even very tiny sampling rate.

Comment: What is the process doing? Have you straced it and compared the results?

Comment: I have an experimental program just creating a simple vector (in C++) and one program in python creating a list of integers. I'm not sure how I can find out about the differences from strace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-deterministic process may obviously result in different memory usage each time. For example, you will never be able to run a large program like Gimp or Chrome and get the same number twice, even if you do the same operation.

However, if you're seeing changes in memory usage for a simple, highly deterministic process, you probably have Address Space Layout Randomization turned on.

Here's an example `foo.c`:

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

You can see it having different memory usage each time:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo

$ /usr/bin/time -f +%M ./foo
+1144
$ /usr/bin/time -f +%M ./foo
+1048
$ /usr/bin/time -f +%M ./foo
+1060
```

This is because ASLR is fully enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
2
```

If you turn it off:

```
$ sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space <<< 0
0
```

You'll get the same value:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f +%M ./foo
+1144
$ /usr/bin/time -f +%M ./foo
+1144
$ /usr/bin/time -f +%M ./foo
+1144
```

But don't forget to turn it back on for the added security:

```
sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space <<< 2
```